# How to connect dynamic db value from one html element to another?

Tags: php, mysql, database, zurb-foundation

I had a hard time to formulate this question so it would be understandable, but here goes.

I have a page called apartments.php. On this page I list a number of rows from my database on apartments that you can show interest to rent.
The apartments are printed out like this:

```
<?php               
   foreach ($apartments as $apartment) { ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $apartment['apartments_room'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $apartment['apartments_area'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $apartment['apartments_rent'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $apartment['apartments_address'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $apartment['apartments_floor'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $apartment['apartments_city'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $apartment['apartments_freeFromDate'] ?></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-reveal-id="<?php echo $apartment['apartments_id'] ?>" name="id" class="button">Apply!</a></td>
     </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Each apartment that gets printed out has its own button. When you press this button, a modal / popup will show. 
And here's my problem.

When the modal pops up I want it to show the information of the apartment from witch I pressed the button. 
So the data-reveal-id value from the button (that represent the specific apartment's db-id) is what I need to get into the modal divs id-value. Additionally I need to write out the address of that apartment (the db column 'apartments_address').

So this is how I need it to be:

```
<div id="HERE I NEED TO GET THAT ID" class="reveal-modal">
    <h2>AND HERE I NEED TO PRINT OUT THE NAME OF THE ADDRESS</h2>

    // Here i make room for an application form, but that's irrelevant...
</div>
```

This shouldn't be a hard thing, right? I hope you can help me out. Thanks!

(For more details if it matters, I'm using the modal of Foundation Zurb 4.)

Comment: Why not something like using jquery and `$(this).attr`

Comment: Use `$_GET` variables?

Comment: ...or `$_POST` variables...

Answer (score 1):

First, your html isn't linking to a new page:

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $apartment['apartments_id'] ?>">
```

This should probably look something like this:

```
<a href="streetEdit.php?id=<?php echo $apartment['apartments_id'] ?>">
```

Then you can create a new php page named streetEdit.php
in that page, you can select the appropriate row from the database

```
$sql = "select * from myApartmentsTable where id = {$_GET['id']}";
```

See how the ID passed in the URL above shows up in $_GET?

next, do your query using the sql and output it on the page.

inside that you need an html form. Use a hidden input to keep track of the ID you are editing:

```
<form method="POST" action="updateStreet.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $apartment['apartments_id'] ?>">
    <input type="text" name="streetName" value="<?php echo $apartment['streetName'] ?>"
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then you need to write updateStreet.php. Since the form was POSTed you will use $_POST instead of $_GET

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$streetName = $_POST['streetName'];
```

Note, you should use PDO for doing your sql queries

```
$sql = "update apartments set streetName = :name where id = :id";

$pdo = new PDO();

$stmt = $pdo->prepareStatement($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $streetName );
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

This will prevent SQL injection attacks.. Ask further if you have more questions

Comment: I reformulated my question because I don't know if I made it too clear from the beginning. My bad.